# windows10の環境で、dockerによるpython3.8の起動を行おうとした際、Conflict エラーが発生する

Tags: docker

Windows PowerShellにて、python3.8の環境を取得後、以下のコマンドを実行してもエラーが発生する。
尚、python3.8の環境を取得については、取得中にエラーが発生したので、再度、pullコマンド実行にて取得は完了。
また、dockerは、スタートメニューより、起動操作を行っています。・・・クジラの表示のアンテナのようなものは動いている状態です。
処置方法について、ご教示願います。

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker run --name python38 -i -t python:3.8 /bin/bash
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/python38" is already in use by container "d1211999633dfda8a20fff1669c747789dcf2d05f3c96cd9a055f29937ec2aca". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(自分の環境はWindowsではないのですが、概ね同じ表示になるかと思います)

初回、

```
docker run --name python38 -i -t python:3.8 /bin/bash
```

を実行した後、 `exit` 等で bash から抜けるとこのコンテナは停止します。
が、削除されるわけではありません。
[`docker ps`コマンド](http://docs.docker.jp/engine/reference/commandline/ps.html)に`-a`オプションを付けると停止したコンテナを含めて一覧表示できます。

```
 $ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
5305dd66b533        python:3.8          "/bin/bash"         8 seconds ago       Exited (0) 4 seconds ago                       python38
```

この状態で冒頭のコマンドを再度実行すると、そのようなエラーになります。
おそらく前回実行したコンテナはもう不要だと思うので、削除すればエラーは解消します。

```
docker rm python38
```

コマンドで削除できます([参考](http://docs.docker.jp/engine/reference/commandline/rm.html))。
削除すれば名前の衝突が解消されますので、また`pyhon38`という名前でコンテナを作成できるようになります。

---

冒頭の`docker run` コマンドに `--rm` オプションを指定しておけば、コンテナ停止時に自動で削除されます([参考](http://docs.docker.jp/engine/reference/commandline/run.html))。
こちらも今回有用かもしれません。

Comment: ご指摘の通り、操作を行ったのですが、別のエラーが発生します。別途、質問させていただきます。・・・ご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

エラーメッセージに原因と対処方法がそのまま書いてあると思うのですが。

"python38"という名前は既に使われていて衝突するので他の名前に変えるかコンテナを削除してください、ということでしょう。同じ名前で複数起動しているのでしょうか？

だから`--name python38`の`python38`の部分を、その都度変えるなり何か前後に追加するなりして同じ名前にならないようにすれば良いのでは？
あるいは結果的に複数起動しているのなら、以前に起動したものは終了させておくとか。